# Draw a hash table horizontally

Tags: forest, picture-mode

How to create this design?

[image]

It's possible with `forest`?

Comment: You can do that with a simple tabular and `hhline` .

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\cellsize}
\setlength{\cellsize}{6mm}

\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {
    draw,
    anchor=west,
    minimum width=\cellsize,
    minimum height=\cellsize,
    text width=\cellsize,
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    line width=1pt,
    execute at begin node = {\small\centering}
  }
}

% current x coord
\newlength{\xcoord}
% current y coord
\newlength{\ycoord}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_template_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_template_tl {
  \node[cell,*1] at (*2) {*3};
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\drawnode}{O{}m}{
  % load template
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl \l_template_tl
  % fill node parameters
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {*1} {\u{l_tmpa_tl}} \l_tmpb_tl
  
  % increment x coord
  \dim_add:Nn \xcoord {\cellsize}
  % fill node location
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\dim_use:N \xcoord, \dim_use:N \ycoord}
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {*2} {\u{l_tmpa_tl}} \l_tmpb_tl
  
  % fill node text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {*3} {\u{l_tmpa_tl}} \l_tmpb_tl
  
  % use node
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}
% initialize x, y coords before drawing
\setlength{\xcoord}{0mm}
\setlength{\ycoord}{0mm}

\drawnode[fill]{}
\drawnode{1}
\drawnode{2}
\drawnode{3}
\drawnode[draw=green]{4}
\drawnode[draw=green]{5}
\drawnode[draw=green]{6}

% draw another table
% initialize x, y coords before drawing
\setlength{\xcoord}{0mm}
\setlength{\ycoord}{-2cm}

\drawnode[draw=orange,fill=orange]{}
\drawnode{1}
\drawnode{2}
\drawnode{3}
\drawnode[draw=red]{4}
\drawnode[draw=blue]{5}
\drawnode[draw=green]{6}
\drawnode{7}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Adding extra information**

Use starred version of `\drawnode`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\cellsize}
\setlength{\cellsize}{6mm}

\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {
    draw,
    anchor=west,
    minimum width=\cellsize,
    minimum height=\cellsize,
    text width=\cellsize,
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    line width=1pt,
    execute at begin node = {\small\centering}
  }
}

% current x coord
\newlength{\xcoord}
% current y coord
\newlength{\ycoord}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_template_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_template_tl {
  \node[cell,*1] at (*2) {*3};
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\drawnode}{sO{}m}{
  % load template
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl \l_template_tl
  % fill node parameters
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {*1} {\u{l_tmpa_tl}} \l_tmpb_tl
  
  % increment x coord if it is not starred
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\dim_add:Nn \xcoord {\cellsize}}
  % fill node location
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\dim_use:N \xcoord, \dim_use:N \ycoord}
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {*2} {\u{l_tmpa_tl}} \l_tmpb_tl
  
  % fill node text
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#3}
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {*3} {\u{l_tmpa_tl}} \l_tmpb_tl
  
  % use node
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{tikzpicture}
% initialize x, y coords before drawing
\setlength{\xcoord}{0mm}
\setlength{\ycoord}{0mm}

\drawnode[fill]{}
\drawnode{1}
% starred command will not increment x coord
\drawnode*[draw=none,yshift=5mm]{\tiny id1}
\drawnode*[draw=none,yshift=8mm]{\tiny id2}
\drawnode{2}
\drawnode{3}
\drawnode[draw=green]{4}
\drawnode[draw=green]{5}
\drawnode[draw=green]{6}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to insert an identifier above the frames?

Comment: It is possible, but it depends on what type of identifier you want to insert. See the example above.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment, it can be done with a simple tabular, xcolor and hhline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline, array}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bigstrut} 


\begin{document}

\sffamily\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{1ex}\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{!{\color{black}\vrule width 1pt}wc{3.2mm}}*{3}{|wc{3.2mm}}|}
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---->{\arrayrulecolor{SeaGreen!60}}|---|<{\arrayrulecolor{black}} }
\cellcolor{black}\bigstrut & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---->{\arrayrulecolor{SeaGreen!60}}|---|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using forest for this wouldn't be my first thought either, but as the OP asked for forest specifically ...

We use a phantom node as the root; all the other other nodes are children of the root. The overlapping-borders effect is achieved by setting the TikZ option `outer xsep=0`. (And the nodes are drawn `thick`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}    
\begin{forest}
  [,phantom,s sep=0,for descendants={draw,thick,outer xsep=0}
    [\phantom{0},fill]
    [1]
    [2]
    [3]
    [4,for current and following siblings=green]
    [5]
    [6]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result for the original request]

Control over the z-order of the nodes is possible using `draw tree processing order`. This is the nodewalk style telling forest in which order to draw nodes, see section 3.4.3 of the manual.

It is easiest to define a nodewalk using the `.nodewalk style` handler, see section 3.8.8 of the manual. To get the crazy-looking `c1b7b4b5b6b2b3`, write down the order in which you want to draw the nodes (`1745623`; each number means "move to the Nth child"; the nodes are renumbered in this example to match the child numbers), separate the numbers by `b` (move back (using a fake step)), and precede the entire thing by `c` (current; as the root is a phantom node, this does nothing, really, but it gives us a node to return to by `b`). In this particular case, where each `back` is moving up to the parent (`u`), `1u7u4u5u6u2u3` would work just as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  draw tree processing order/.nodewalk style=c1b7b4b5b6b2b3,
  [,phantom,s sep=0,for descendants={draw,thick,outer xsep=0}
    [1,fill,text=white]
    [2,red]
    [3,green]
    [4,orange]
    [5,blue]
    [6,yellow]
    [7,brown]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Controlling the z-order of nodes]